# Kendo Grid autoFitColumn is not working properly

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using Kendo grid, I want to show all the data so I used `autoFitColumn`. Sometimes it's working and sometimes it gets shrined all the columns. When I click on the grid then it gets resized properly. Can anyone help me out of this issue?

```
   $('#CSCGrid').kendoGrid({
                                toolbar: ["excel", "pdf"],
                                excel: {
                                    fileName: "A.xlsx",
                                    proxyURL: "Excel_Export_Save",
                                    forceProxy: true,
                                    allPages: true
                                },
                                pdf: {
                                    allPages: true,
                                    avoidLinks: true,
                                    paperSize: "A4",
                                    margin: { top: "0.1cm", left: "0.1cm", right: "0.1cm", bottom: "0.1cm" },
                                    landscape: true,
                                    repeatHeaders: true,
                                    template: $("#page-template").html(),
                                    scale: 0.8
                                },


                                dataSource: {
                                    type: "json",
                                    schema: {
                                        model: {
                                            fields: {
                                                F: { type: "string" },
                                                T: { type: "string" },
                                                R_CD: { type: "string" },
                                                R_DESC: { type: "string" },
                                                CBY: { type: "string" },
                                                CDT: { type: "date" },
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    data: data,
                                    pageSize: 10,
                                },
                                resizable: true,
                                sortable: true,
                                filterable: true,
                                columnMenu: true,
                                // reorderable: true,
                                //scrollable: false,
                                //width: 'auto',
                                pageable: {
                                    buttonCount: 5,
                                    pageSizes: [5, 10, 50, 'All'],
                                    message: {
                                        empty: 'No Data',
                                        allPages: 'All'
                                    }
                                },
                                 dataBound: function (e) {
                                  
                                    for (var i = 0; i < this.columns.length; i++) {
                                        this.autoFitColumn(i);
                                    }

                                
                                },
                                columns: [{
                                    field: "F",
                                    title: "F",
                                }, {
                                    field: "T", 
                                    title: "T",
                                }, {
                                    field: "R_CD",
                                    title: "R",
                                }, {
                                    field: "R_DESC",
                                    title: "R", 
                                }, {
                                    field: "CBY",
                                    title: "M", 
                                }, {
                                    field: "CDT",
                                    title: "M", format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}",
                                },
                                ]
                             });
                            setTimeout(function () {
                                kendo.resize($('#CSCGrid'));

                            }, 200)
```

Comment: Is there any reason for calling `kendo.resize` ? This would basically redraw the entire Grid, and the data binding might not have occurred at that point. Calling the `autoFitColumn` in the dataBound handler should be [sufficient](https://dojo.telerik.com/oyubUvIY).